# fixing a for loop in python where you don't use the variable

Tags: python

I have a 'for' loop where I need t iterate through a list but do not need the iterative variable named 'node'. What would be a more elegant way to do this?

```
for node in NODES:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        tex_pairs_to_swap_dict[NODES[i]] = NODES[i+1]
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is a case of actually needing the index in `NODES`. You get this using `range(len(NODES))` but `range()` also supports an optional parameter of `step` that would allow you step through this 2 at a time (note: you also have to include the `start` if you want the `step`):

```
for i in range(0, len(NODES), 2):
    tex_pairs_to_swap_dict[NODES[i]] = NODES[i+1]
```

This assumes there is an even number of entries in the list and will raise an `IndexError` if it isn't.

Alternatively, if all you are trying to do is step through the list 2 at a time you could also use:

```
it = iter(NODES)
for k, v in zip(it, it):
    tex_pairs_to_swap_dict[k] = v
```

This is equivalent to the above without creating the `it` variable:

```
for k, v in zip(*[iter(NODES)]*2):
    tex_pairs_to_swap_dict[k] = v
```

This will silently ignore the last value in an odd sized list.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way to do this would be to use a range. I would recommend you do this:

```
for i in range(len(NODES)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        tex_pairs_to_swap_dict[NODES[i]] = NODES[i+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `enumerate` function, which returns a tuple with the index and the item.

```
for i, _ in enumerate(NODES):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        tex_pairs_to_swap_dict[NODES[i]] = NODES[i+1]
```

Answer (score -1):

In python you can define a for loop without a variable and still access the contents of that. For example:

```
x = [1,2,3]

for _ in x: print (_)
```

will provide you an **output** of:

```
1
2
3
```

You can also do this with dictionaries. For example:

```
x = {1:10, 2:20}

for _,__ in x.items(): print (_,__)
```

The **output** of this will be:

```
1 10
2 20
```

In summary, you can use _ as a variable and reference it. While you may think there is no variable defined, it is still a throwaway variable. More details about _ can be found in this post: [What is the purpose of the single underscore "_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)

Based on this, you can rewrite your code as follows:

```
for _ in NODES:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        tex_pairs_to_swap_dict[NODES[i]] = NODES[i+1]
    i += 1
```

With this, you don't need to use the variable `node`